# Made a form in HTML and PHP but unable to figure out what is wrong

Tags: php, html

I made a form to email the data to an email ID. 
But upon filling up the form and submitting, the browser is saying:

> Server error. The website encountered an error while retrieving `http://localhost/process.php`.

Here is the code:

### form1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method = "post" action = "process.php">
Enter your name <input type = "text" name = "namee" id = "namee" value = "enter your name" />
Enter your phone number <input type = "text" name = "phone" id = "phone" />
<br>
<input type  = "submit" value = "post it!" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

### process.php

```
<?php

$person_name = $_POST["namee"];
$person_number = $_POST["phone"];

$to = "example234671_1@gmail.com";
$subject = "form filled up";
$body = $person_name. "<br>" $person_number . "<br>" . $person_name ;


mail($to, $subject, $body);

echo "Thank you!" ;
?>
```

What is the error??

Comment: What do your server logs say?

Comment: this is what the server log say --> [Sat Aug 31 19:29:06 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$person_number' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/process.php on line 9, referer: http://localhost/form1.html     .... @Quentin

Comment: Try adding a `$from="email@example.com";` and adding `$header = "From: ". $from . " $from " . "\r\n";` then do `mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);` along with `Cobra Fast's` answer.

Comment: In order to have line breaks using `<br>` you will need your headers to be as `text/html`

Comment: Yes. Got it. I had missed a concatenator. It was a silly mistake. I must keep these in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to format email properly, headers using `text/html` must be used for `<br>` as line breaks.

Otherwise, your email body will appear as `John Doe<br>213-555-0123<br>etc.`

Plus, as the others have already stated, a missing concatenate in:

```
$body = $person_name. "<br>" $person_number . "<br>" . $person_name ;
```

which should read as:

```
$body = $person_name. "<br>" . $person_number . "<br>" . $person_name;
```

#### Rewrite with added headers:

```
<?php

$person_name = $_POST["namee"];
$person_number = $_POST["phone"];
$to = "example@gmail.com";
$subject = "form filled up";
$from="email@example.com";
$body = $person_name. "<br>" . $person_number . "<br>" . $person_name;

$header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header .= "From: ". $from . " $from " . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
echo "Thank you!";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a newbie in PHP. I must keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

```
$body = $person_name. "<br>" $person_number . "<br>" . $person_name ;
```

This line is wrong, you're missing a concatenator.

```
$body = $person_name. "<br>" . $person_number . "<br>" . $person_name ;
```

Comment: Yes. Got it. It was a silly mistake. I must keep these in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There's a syntax error here.

```
$body = $person_name. "<br>" $person_number . "<br>" . $person_name ;
```

`"<br>"` needs to be followed by a concatenation dot, like so:

```
$body = $person_name. "<br>" . $person_number . "<br>" . $person_name ;
```

While developing, you'll want to enable displaying php errors though. Have a look at [PHP Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).

Comment: Yes. Got it. It was a silly mistake. I must keep these in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Like it's already said you missed a concatenation dot but I also see another error.

```
"<br>"
```

is HTML and without the right content type you won't be able to show HTML in your email.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php for more information and examples.

OR use \n for newlines.